# Flexigrid - how to turn off row selection

Tags: flexigrid

Is it possible to turn off the row selection feature on [Flexigrid](http://www.flexigrid.info/)?
It's somewhat annoying when you haven't implemented anything that makes use of the selection.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out you need to change the singleSelect property to true.

```
singleSelect: true
```

Comment: This disables *multi-row* selection. Flapper's answer below disables *all* selection.

Comment: Oddly enough, this disables selection as of the most recent version. And, oddly enough, I'm looking for both options.

Comment: @JohnBaughman It's working in the recent version available on GitHub

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately Mr Flibble's accepted answer does not stop all selection capability, it merely restricts it to one row.
To disable it completely, add a new property to the $.extend block (around line 20)

```
// apply default properties
p = $.extend({
<SNIP>
onSubmit: false, // using a custom populate function
disableSelect: true
```

Then in the .click section of the row (around line 754) add a check for the property

```
$(this)
.click(
 function (e)
 {
  var obj = (e.target || e.srcElement); if (obj.href || obj.type) return true;
  if (p.disableSelect) return true;
  $(this).toggleClass('trSelected');
  if (p.singleSelect) $(this).siblings().removeClass('trSelected');
 }
)
```

Comment: Is it possible to turn off the row selection feature on Flexigrid? Yes this is the solution. Good job Flapper! +1

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is a bit old but I came upon it looking for the same thing. The singleSelect didn't work for me as I didn't want to be able to select any row. I found that I could remove any row selection with a single line of code:

```
$('.grid tr').unbind('click');
```

This a course removes all bindings on the table row so if you needed the binding you won't have it unless you rebind later but I needed to remove any and all row selection on my table. I didn't need to touch the flexigrid code to do so which I liked a bit more than previous answers.